# Firebase Google SignIn not working after few login Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am using firebase Google SignIn Authentication, App is working fine initially but after few try , login is not getting any success , is there any way to test google auth in debug mode, I tried to put `AndroidDebug SHA` key but its not working !
Getting this error.

```
[BeginSignInOperation] BeginSignInOperation failed. [CONTEXT service_id=212 ]
    czxt: asco
        at asgj.apply(:com.google.android.gms@232316037@23.23.16 (150400-540660214):5)
        at cztd.d(:com.google.android.gms@232316037@23.23.16 (150400-540660214):2)
        at czte.run(:com.google.android.gms@232316037@23.23.16 (150400-540660214):10)
        at acav.c(:com.google.android.gms@232316037@23.23.16 (150400-540660214):6)
        at acav.run(:com.google.android.gms@232316037@23.23.16 (150400-540660214):7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at acgd.run(:com.google.android.gms@232316037@23.23.16 (150400-540660214):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
    Caused by: asco
        at ascn.a(:com.google.android.gms@232316037@23.23.16 (150400-540660214):0)
        at asco.d(:com.google.android.gms@232316037@23.23.16 (150400-540660214):0)
        at mnv.a(:com.google.android.gms@232316037@23.23.16 (150400-540660214):85)
        at asgh.a(:com.google.android.gms@232316037@23.23.16 (150400-540660214):0)
        at cztw.d(:com.google.android.gms@232316037@23.23.16 (150400-540660214):2)
        at czty.run(:com.google.android.gms@232316037@23.23.16 (150400-540660214):9)
```

I am using

Google Play service auth

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.5.0
```

Firebase Auth

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.0.3
```

I followed this example
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

This is how I provide object for SignIn and signUp

```
@Provides
    @Named(SIGN_IN_REQUEST)
    fun provideSignInRequest(
        app: Application
    ) = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
        .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(
            BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
                .setSupported(true)
                .setServerClientId(app.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
                .build()
        )
        .setAutoSelectEnabled(false)
        .build()

    @Provides
    @Named(SIGN_UP_REQUEST)
    fun provideSignUpRequest(
        app: Application
    ) = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
        .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(
            BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
                .setSupported(true)
                .setServerClientId(app.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
                .build()
        )
        .build()
```

Here I am calling in my repo

```
override suspend fun oneTapSignInWithGoogle(): OneTapSignInResponse {
        return try {
            val signInResult = oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signInRequest).await()
            Response.Success(signInResult)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            try {
                val signUpResult = oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signUpRequest).await()
                Response.Success(signUpResult)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Response.Failure(e)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the code that produces that error?

Comment: @AlexMamo added the more code

Comment: I wasn't necessarily asking for much but to indicate the line that produces that error. Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle). It's a working solution.

Comment: @AlexMamo oh its you , Yes already I took reference from your repo.
Thanks for your repo

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a phone identification? For some of the authentication methods you need to identify the testing accounts or else it will block them to avoid spams. On top of that, there is a max quota for free accounts per day (for SMS it's 50)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Eliza, I am not using phone identification. I m using Firebase Authentication

Comment: I'm confused. On Firebase, there are multiple ways for identification (email, social, Google play, phone, and more). Which one are you using?

Comment: ah Sorry , I am usingGoogle Login !

Comment: Is this happening only on your test user? How many attempts did you try, and in how much time?

Comment: yes its testing mode, I tried 4 times in row , and its trowing this error since yesterday evening.
I think my login account got suspended for 24 hours,

Comment: yeah I'm suspecting the same thing. I'll give it a wild guess and assume you're using the free plan?

Comment: Yes I am using free plan

Comment: Give it 24h and update the thread if you still have issues

Comment: Yes, its Woking now, it was suspended for 24 hours ! Thanks